# jquery selectable - Div and Canvas

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery selectable plugin and running it to a situation as follows.

Please take a look at this image 
[image: jquery selection]

The html5 canvas is enclosed inside a DIV. But the canvas is bigger than the DIV size on purpose. The round rectangle is always of the size of the DIV. The canvas is bigger by say 10 pixel on each side of the DIV boundary. In the above image, the blue boundary represents the canvas.

I have jquery selectable and it selects all objects that are of class ="mt_obj".

The DIV is assigned this class but the canvas is not assigned this class.

The side effect is when I use the marquee selection (rubberband) and if it falls in the canvas region then the object gets selected. So if I click between the blue border and the rounded square border, the object gets selected. The desired behavior is to select only when the user clicks on the gray rounder square.

Here is the HTML code. **Is there a way in jquery selectable or class selection to avoid the selection if it is a canvas object?**. I think the canvas selection propogates to the DIV since the div is the parent of canvas.

```
<div style="display: block; position: absolute; 
top: 181px; left: 217px; width: 398px; height: 34px; z-index: 1;" 
class="mt_obj ui-resizable ui-draggable ui-selected ui-resizable-autohide">
<canvas  style="position: relative; 
top: -10px; left: -17.4561px;" width="432" height="54">
</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your entire code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I'm guessing that selectable uses any or all of the mouseover, mouseout, mouseenter, and mouseleave events to trigger a selection. With that in mind you may be able to do something like this after you call `selectable`:

```
$("div.mt_obj canvas").bind("mouseover mouseout", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You could try the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events in there too.

Comment: it did not work. I even tried binding a click event on canvas but nothing gets triggered. Does jquery recognize canvas element?

Comment: Bummer. Sorry I don't have any direct answers, but since no one else has jumped in with any "real" answers, I have a couple of more suggestions.  There are a few possible options for the selectable that may help. Check out the docs [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#option-cancel) under options. The `cancel` option lets you select types of objects to exclude (like `{cancel:'canvas'}`), which may or may not help with the propagation issue. The `filter` option lets you more specifically define objects to select (like `{filter: 'div.mt_obj'}`).